# How to prove $\cos : C \to X$ is a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $C=\mathbb C - \{n \pi \mid n\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $X = \mathbb C - \{ \pm1\}$, than $$\cos : C \to X$$ is a covering map, also the fundamental group of $X$ is not abelian.

I can see why this is a covering map by thinking how the $\cos$ graph looks like in real number, but I don't know how to write that down as a proof. More precisely, what I need to show?

(My idea is: Since the function $\cos$ is continuous and surjective. Is that enough to show for every $x \in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that $\cos^{-1}(U)$ is a union of disjoint open sets in $C$.)

Also, can someone give me some idea why the fundamental group of $X$ is not abelian.

Comment: The complex plane is homeomorphic to the euclidean plane. If you remove a point from the plane you get the free group on one generator. What happens when you remove two points? Is that group abelian?

Comment: What you need to show? Well, you need to show that that map is a covering space! Do you recall the definition?

Comment: How do you know that $\cos$ is surjective ( not subjective, as you write ...) ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks, ill fix that typo. Since $\cos z = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$, so it is easy to see that $\cos$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

We have the infinite covering maps $z\mapsto e^{iz}$ and the two-sheeted covering map  $w\mapsto \frac 12 ( w+\frac 1w)$.
The cosine is the composition of those and is thus a covering map.
Your task will be to determine the domain and codomain of the above maps in order to obtain a complete proof.

**Warning**
In some extremely pathological cases the composition of two covering maps may no longer be a covering map but this need not concern us here.